# build json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Let's say that I have some json data like this:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "text":"text1"
},{
    "id":2,
    "text":"text2"
}]
```

How do I build something like this in javascript, for example, I wanna have a javascript variable `my_json_object` that contains the json object above, but how can I build that json object in javascript or jquery?

Thank you

Comment: That's not JSON data, it's an array of objects. JSON is what you get if you call `JSON.stringify()` on it.

Comment: I do something like this. `var my_json_object = []; var obj1 = {}; obj1.id = 1;obj1.text = 'text1';my_json_object.push(obj1);obj2 = {};obj2.id=2;obj2.text='text2';my_json_object.push(obj2);JSON.stringify(my_json_object);`

Answer (score 1):

Simply try on your console :

```
var obj = [{
             "id":1,
             "text":"text1"
          },{
              "id":2,
              "text":"text2"
         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_object = // what you already have; it's perfectly valid JavaScript
```